# Ubuntu 14.04 Unity got slow during the last couple of updates

Tags: unity, 14.04, desktop-environments

I've been using Ubuntu since 12.04 and have not really experienced any issues until a couple of weeks ago when my PC got really slow and all software as well. Switching workspaces is more of a lagfest than a smooth animation.

I don't think its a hardware issue since the specs are pretty high-end except for the graphics card.

- AMD FX-8320 8 Core
- Nvidia GTX630
- 16GB DDR3 Ram (1600)

Running;

- Ubuntu 14.04 amd64
- Nvidia proprietary drivers 331.38 (Have also tested noeveau driver but no cigar)

Even typing is slow, I can sometimes type 3 words before they appear in this text-box on askubuntu. I tried switching to Gnome but that made things even worse, so I switched back to unity.

I have no clue as to where one would start looking for issues, so I turn to you guys for tips.

**Edit** So it seems that switching to a lightweight DE fixes some of the issues but seriously, shouldn't my specs be able to handle Unity or Gnome? I have another equal workstation but running Windows 7 Ultimate instead, and I have never experienced anything that even resembles lag on that PC - even with 4 android emulators running simultaneously.

I'll switch to a lighter DE if needed but I'm having a real hard time thinking that the developers expect the public to have much better PC's than my specs when running Ubuntu - I'm thinking my specs is a bit overkill even cut in half (except for the graphics). Plus I like having a modern look and feel, which none of the lighter DE provides (everything looks like it was made in the 1980's).

**Edit** I changed the IOMMU bios setting and reinstalled Ubuntu without any proprietary drivers and now everything seems to be working at last.

Comment: Nice to see you worked it out. You can use `$ top` to debug. It will easily tell you where the issue lies.

PS: 331.38 is better than noeveau for non-hybrid cards.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Thanks for your input but `top` didn't show anything out of the ordinary. CPU was at about 2% usage (35% when I was working with emulators), no more than 3-4GB of memory has ever been utilized at the same time and I'm not using any 3D modelling software or play games on this workstation so my graphics card is just for Unity/other DE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the IOMMU bios setting is a real issue for many with Gigabyte mainboards. After having toggled this setting and re-installed Ubuntu it all runs smoothly and nice again.

Also, having toggled the bios setting Ubuntu now finds compatible drivers for my hardware, earlier I had to manually setup realtek chipset and graphics drivers.